# The same DataBinding isn't updating when I change one of 2 bound TextBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, textbox

I have 2 TextBoxes that use the same BindingSource.  When I update one TextBox and lose focus the other TextBox does not update it's property to the new value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    using System.Data;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    namespace TextBoxes
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            BindingSource bs1 = new BindingSource();
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.Load += Form1_Load;
            }
            void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Name");
                dt.Rows.Add("Donald Trump");
                dt.Rows.Add("Sergei Rachmaninoff");
                dt.Rows.Add("Bill Gates");

                bs1.DataSource = dt;
                bs1.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
                bs1.CurrencyManager.Position = 1;

                textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs1, "Name");
                textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs1, "Name");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can force the refresh by using endEdit - if you put this on the textchanged then as you change textbox1, textbox2 will automatically change.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bs1.EndEdit();
}
```

(and do the same for the textchanged of textbox2 if you want reciprocal updates).

Though I would say if you're binding to a list, wouldn't combos be better?

Comment: Thanks NDJ.  I want to edit a datagridview row with a dialog box.  It is what my boss wants.

Comment: The solution you provided makes the most sense for this issue.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Add the below methods in your code... it will work...

**FormDesigner.cs**

```
        this.textBox1.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_LostFocus);
        this.textBox2.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox2_LostFocus);
```

**Form.cs**

```
        private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.DataBindings.Clear();
            textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs1, "Name");
        }

        private void textBox2_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
            textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs1, "Name");
        }
```